# Search password with letters in uppercase with recursion c#

Tags: c#, recursion

I'm trying to do task, where I have to search password. The input is the string in lowcase, the output is all case sensative strings from input string.
For example: input "ab42", output "ab42", "aB42", "Ab42", "AB42".
I've done this, but I have problem with recursion, could somebody help me? Thanks.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var res = AlternateCharCases("cat");
        foreach (var r in res)
            Console.WriteLine(r);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
    public static List<string> AlternateCharCases(string lowercaseWord)
    {
        var result = new List<string>();
        AlternateCharCases(lowercaseWord.ToCharArray(), 0, result);
        return result;
    }

    static void AlternateCharCases(char[] word, int startIndex, List<string> result)
    {
        if (startIndex == word.Length)
        {
            var d = new char[word.Length];
            Array.Copy(word, d, word.Length);
            result.Add(new string(d));
            result.Sort();
            result = result.Distinct().ToList();
            return;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < word.Length; i++)
        {
            word[i] = Char.ToUpper(word[i]);
            AlternateCharCases(word, startIndex + 1, result);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add details about the problem with recurssion.

Comment: and what will be be the output of abcDef123???

Comment: Why are you using recursion?  You'd be much better off putting this in a `for` loop, particularly if you need to run this many times.  You say that this is for a password - are you trying to hash every combination of upper/lowercase characters for a rainbow table or brute-forcing?  If so, you'll need a much faster algorithm.  Because if you're just trying to do a string comparison to match any case there are far more efficient ways to do it.

Comment: @pcdev This is task for understanding recurison, and I need to use it.

Comment: @J.SMTBCJ15 input string can be only in lowcase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to have a good think about what you're trying to do here: What is the recursion part for?

In its current form you are basically saying:

```
// Pseudocode
A:
if (startIndex == len(word))
{
    return SortedDistinctList();
}

foreach (char in word)
{
    word.SetCharToUppercase(char);
    startIndex++;
    Goto A:
}
```

That's not really recursion. I haven't run it but I think you'll end up with just one uppercase word after `Distinct`ing.  Part of the problem is that you're trying to mix recursion with a `foreach` loop, but you're trying to get your `foreach` loop to do all the work.

Recursion is about (a) breaking the problem into repeatable chunks, and (b) knowing when to stop calling yourself (the "break" condition).  The repeatable chunk of work here is making a letter either uppercase or lowercase, and the recursion is traversing the word building up BOTH uppercase and lowercase versions for each character.  When we get to the end of the word we can return that "version" so that the program flow can descend down another branch of the recursion tree and get additional chunks completed.

Think of it like this:

> ```
>                   "cat"
>                 ____^____
>             __ c         C__
>            /   \        /   \
>          a      A      a     A
>         / \    / \    / \   / \
>        t   T  t   T  t   T t   T
> ```

You have to traverse every branch and when you get to a leaf node, add that word to your list.

Try something like this (I'll leave it to you as an exercise to translate the pseudocode into C#):

```
// Pseudocode
static void AlternateCharCases(char[] word, int index, List<string> result)
{
    // This is our recursive "break" condition - we return each time a word is added
    // to the list, NOT just when we have finished compiling the list 
    if (startIndex == len(word))
    {
        AddWordToList(word);
        return; // This goes up 1 level of recursion, NOT necessarily back to the top
    }
    else
    {
        // Keep lowercase for this char and keep traversing:
        AlternateCharCases(word, index + 1, result);

        // Now uppercase this char and keep traversing:
        SetCharToUpper(word, index);
        AlternateCharCases(word, index + 1, result);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thx, I've already done it and posted, but mark your answer like right one!

Answer (score 1):

You could try this instead:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> AlternateCharCases(string lowercaseWord)
{
    if (lowercaseWord.Length == 1)
    {
        yield return lowercaseWord;
        yield return lowercaseWord.ToUpper();
    }
    else
    {
        foreach (var nested in AlternateCharCases(lowercaseWord.Substring(1)))
        {
            yield return lowercaseWord.Substring(0, 1) + nested;
            yield return lowercaseWord.Substring(0, 1).ToUpper() + nested;
        }
    }
}
```

Your example code gives me:

```
cat
Cat
cAt
CAt
caT
CaT
cAT
CAT
```

Comment: I just want to change last method's body

Comment: @Alexandr - I would consider trying not to use it. The method signature is rather awkward. And your use of `int startIndex` makes it difficult to get right - it is adding many more words than necessary.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var res = AlternateCharCases("cat");
        foreach (var r in res)
            Console.WriteLine(r);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
    public static List<string> AlternateCharCases(string lowercaseWord)
    {
        var result = new List<string>();
        AlternateCharCases(lowercaseWord, lowercaseWord.ToCharArray(), 0, result);
        result = result.Distinct().ToList();
        return result;
    }

    static void AlternateCharCases(string initialWord, char[] word, int startIndex, List<string> result)
    {
        if (startIndex == word.Length)
            result.Add(new string(word));
        else
        {
            if(!Char.IsLetter(initialWord[startIndex]))
            {
                word[startIndex] = initialWord[startIndex];
                AlternateCharCases(initialWord, word, startIndex + 1, result);
            }
            else
            {
                word[startIndex] = initialWord[startIndex];
                AlternateCharCases(initialWord, word, startIndex + 1, result);
                word[startIndex] = Char.ToUpper(initialWord[startIndex]);
                AlternateCharCases(initialWord, word, startIndex + 1, result);
            }
        }

    }

}
```